# What is best pratices of naming api routing?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I don't know what is the best way to define Rest API convention, what I am doing so far is that

**For CRUD operations I will let HttpVerb do the work such as**

GET /projects

POST /projects/{projectId}

PUT /projects/{projectId}

DELETE /projects/{projectId}

**For operations other than CRUD**

POST /projects/{projectId}/changeStatus

**And for relation entities**

GET /projects/{projectId}/workItems/

And in your case what would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing good so far. It will be a lot easier when you can determine a resource. You need to ask yourself what a resource is.

In your case resources are projects, that's why operations need to be bound to the resources (as you can see that projectId frequently appears in uri).

Here are some example is worth looking at

**1. document**

A document resource is a singular concept that is akin to an object instance or database record. In REST, you can view it as a single resource inside resource collection. A document’s state representation typically includes both fields with values and links to other related resources.

Use “singular” name to denote document resource archetype.

```
http://api.example.com/device-management/managed-devices/{device-id}
http://api.example.com/user-management/users/{id}
http://api.example.com/user-management/users/admin
```

**2. collection**

A collection resource is a server-managed directory of resources. Clients may propose new resources to be added to a collection. However, it is up to the collection to choose to create a new resource, or not. A collection resource chooses what it wants to contain and also decides the URIs of each contained resource.

Use “plural” name to denote collection resource archetype.

```
http://api.example.com/device-management/managed-devices
http://api.example.com/user-management/users
http://api.example.com/user-management/users/{id}/accounts
store
```

A store is a client-managed resource repository. A store resource lets an API client put resources in, get them back out, and decide when to delete them. A store never generates new URIs. Instead, each stored resource has a URI that was chosen by a client when it was initially put into the store.

Use “plural” name to denote store resource archetype.

```
http://api.example.com/cart-management/users/{id}/carts
http://api.example.com/song-management/users/{id}/playlists
```

**3. controller**

A controller resource models a procedural concept. Controller resources are like executable functions, with parameters and return values; inputs and outputs.

Use “verb” to denote controller archetype.

```
http://api.example.com/cart-management/users/{id}/cart/checkout
http://api.example.com/song-management/users/{id}/playlist/play
```